# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape= (None, 864, 864, 2), found shape=(None, 864, 2)

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, complex-numbers

Can anybody explain to me why I still receive the expected shape=(None, 864, 864, 2), found shape=(None, 864, 2), even after I defined the input shape as a 3-dimension [864, 864, 2]?

I am trying to implement the complex-valued convolutional neural network. And I am using this pip install cvnn library ([Link of library](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn))

Here is my code:

```
import cvnn.layers as complex_layers
import tensorflow as tf




model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexInput(input_shape=[864, 864, 2]))  # Always use ComplexInput at the start
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='cart_relu'))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='cart_relu'))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexMaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='cart_relu'))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexFlatten())
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(64, activation='cart_relu'))
model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(10, activation='convert_to_real_with_abs'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
return model
```

Input Shape for the dataset:

```
data shape: (8010, 864, 2)
```

Model Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
complex_conv2d (ComplexConv  (None, 862, 862, 32)     1216
2D)

complex_avg_pooling2d (Comp  (None, 431, 431, 32)     0
lexAvgPooling2D)

complex_conv2d_1 (ComplexCo  (None, 429, 429, 64)     36992
nv2D)

complex_max_pooling2d (Comp  (None, 214, 214, 64)     0
lexMaxPooling2D)

complex_conv2d_2 (ComplexCo  (None, 212, 212, 64)     73856
nv2D)

complex_flatten (ComplexFla  (None, 2876416)          0
tten)

complex_dense (ComplexDense  (None, 64)               368181376
 )

complex_dense_1 (ComplexDen  (None, 10)               1300
 se)

=================================================================
Total params: 368,294,740
Trainable params: 368,294,740
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error I am getting:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape= 
 (None, 864, 864, 2), found shape=(None, 864, 2)
```

Comment: From `data shape: (8010, 864, 2)`, it seems like your inputs are 2D tensors of the shape of (864, 2). If that's the case, the first layer should have `input_shape=(864, 2)`

Comment: In that case, I am getting this error:  ` ValueError: Input 0 of layer "complex_conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 864, 2)`

Comment: Can you explain about your input? Why does it have a shape of (864, 2)? Is it by chance an image of 32x27? In that case, you can reshape your (864, 2)-shaped input into `(32, 27, 2)`.

Comment: This is not an image, it is IQ signal data. If you want to look at the dataset here is the link:  [link](https://mailuc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/wang2ba_ucmail_uc_edu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?ga=1&id=%2Fpersonal%2Fwang2ba%5Fucmail%5Fuc%5Fedu%2FDocuments%2Fgroup%2Fdatasets%5Fpublic%2FHackRF10%5Fdataset%5Fcns22%2Four%5Fday1%2Ezip&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fwang2ba%5Fucmail%5Fuc%5Fedu%2FDocuments%2Fgroup%2Fdatasets%5Fpublic%2FHackRF10%5Fdataset%5Fcns22)